# I am seeing in my emacs mode line the message "Restart Recommended". What causes this message to appear?

Tags: emacs

It seems benign as I've run for weeks (under screen) with this message.  However, I'm curious what triggered it (and it's red banner).

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's [coming from emacs itself](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22Restart+Recommended%22&type=Code) so I am guessing some package you have installed.

Comment: I doubt this is enough information to lead to a meaningful answer. But maybe you'll be lucky.

Comment: Totally shooting in the dark here.  Maybe you installed some modeline add-on package (for example one listed on https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLineConfiguration) and one of those tracks `/etc/motd`?